# Given the nullable type `bool?`, how do I get the non-nullable one `bool`

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm getting this error while trying to run a firebase app. I have tried `flutter upgrade` with no solution to the error

I was hoping to see the refreshed flutter app UI but after running the main.dart it gave this error, the solution to which don't seem to be anywhere.

main.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gated/auth/auth.dart';
import 'package:gated/firebase_options.dart';
//import 'package:gated/auth/login_or_register.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: AuthPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

The error:

```
../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/auth-8.2.0+02/lib/src/auth.dart:481:44: Error: The argument type 'bool?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't.

appVerificationDisabledForTesting: appVerificationDisabledForTesting,

^

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
```

Please help me resolve this!

Comment: Do you have your pubspec.yaml handy? It appears to be an issue with the package `auth-8.2.0+02` but I can't find that on pub.dev. You may want to ensure that you're using the most up to date versions of all packages and that your flutter sdk constraints in the pubspec.yaml are in line with your updated flutter version

Comment: I too cant it on pub.dev and in my pubsec.yaml it's value is 8.2.0+02 Beside that i'm using updated packages. here is my pubsec.yaml  ` auth: ^8.2.0+02
  firebase_auth: ^4.17.9`  and  ` flutter_lints: ^3.0.0`

Comment: It appears that [`package:auth`](https://pub.dev/packages/auth) is discontinued; perhaps you should look for an alternative.

Comment: @jamesdlin can you suggest an alternative. For the life of me I wouldn't be able to find it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JoesephSchmoe can you circle back and look at James's comment and suggest me the alternative? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Abhijeet I'm not familiar with `package:auth` nor with Firebase, but perhaps one of these packages would do what you want? https://pub.dev/packages?q=firebase+auth

Comment: @Abhijeet it would appear that auth enabled you to sign in with firebase, google auth, facebook, and twitter. The thing is: firebase itself supports those. So I believe that you can just use firebase. I'd try to remove it and see what if anything breaks, and then go from there

Comment: @Abhijeet - I just posted an answer (it was too long for a comment), but the TL;DR is that as a stop-gap you could also consider importing directly from the GitHub for the package, which I noted in the answer. You can find more information about how to do git imports [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#dependencies-on-unpublished-packages). I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jamesdlin pointed out: [package:auth](https://pub.dev/packages/auth) is discontinued. According to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/AndriousSolutions/auth) there are more recent commits to the repository that were being submitted by a different user four months ago; the last commit to the pub.dev version was 14 months ago.

So I think you have two options here.

## Door #1: import from git, not pub.dev

You are able to depend on packages directly from a git repository like so:

```yaml
  auth:
    git: 
      url: https://github.com/AndriousSolutions/auth.git
      ref: f6f709c # The commit hash - usually first 7 digits are plenty
```

^ That should be a drop-in replacement for you. Just keep in mind to keep the yaml properly formatted. And be sure to replace your current pubspec line. And the error you got references line numbers that have changed in the newest version: so it should be fixed now.

The downside here is that if you run `flutter pub upgrade` or `flutter pub outdated` it won't find any updates to the auth package anymore because you're no longer pulling from pub- you're pulling from github, so it's on you to keep it up to date.

It's also unclear what the path forward for the package is now- there are no posts that I can find on the GitHub or the pub.dev page to explain how to migrate away from it or any plans for the package going forward.

So this is very much an as-long-as-it-lasts situation, and long term I'd advise you to either (a) fork the repository and take control over the package yourself to keep it up to date for your needs or (b) start looking for alternatives... speaking of...

## Door #2: Look for alternatives

It's not ideal to have to rework some of your codebase, but it looks like `auth` supported firebase, google auth, facebook, and twitter as the official sign in options. The `firebase_auth` package appears to support those within their package. So trying to migrate to [package:firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) is a good place to start.

The advantage there is that by switching to a package that is still maintained, you are less likely to run into issues like this in the future as the sdk introduces possible breaking changes in the future.